# Shortcuts on Kentico Admin UI

Tags: kentico

Is there a way to create shortcuts on the Kentico Admin UI?

These would be used to launch internal applications or pages outside of Kentico commonly utilized by our CMS Users (some of which may deal with Kentico data, and we leverage the Kentico Login).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.  Take a look at the [documentation for creating custom modules](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+custom+modules).

Comment: So, create a custom module that is just a redirect to a specific URL?

Comment: Yep, should be as easy as that.